Having a windows prompt for saving a file be the top form in C#
I wrote an application for opening up different types of data and graphing it.
One issue is that on our company servers that when you open certain files, that it will ask you to save it or not before you do. Unfortunately my application window is above that prompt, so it appears as if the program is frozen. Alt-Tab will allow you to switch to it, but I want to the save prompt go in front of my form instead.
How could I do this?
I don't know where to even start. I made the main form be the active form. I froze the original window when I open any child forms. That prevents weird errors from occurring. But I am at a total loss on how to handle prompts from outside my WinForms.

The following may be of interest: ShowDialog.
